# Найти близкие числа в массиве | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

```
117.81008911132812,
 116.40049913194444,
 132.6966349283854,
 139.83181762695312,
 129.08833482530383,
 99.76490953233507,
 132.69677734375,
 117.81746080186632,
 132.66025119357639,
 100.42313300238715,
 105.30181545681424,
 155.56293063693576,
 120.6885986328125,
 107.1498514811198,
 100.41515435112848,
 105.30535888671875,
 155.5640394422743,
 132.65536159939236,
 137.21171061197916,
 150.28360324435764,
 116.40386962890625,
 172.6755608452691,
 136.65747748480902,
 139.99466281467014,
 137.20905558268228,
 144.14166937934027,
 137.97456868489584,
 144.14078097873264,
 172.5401136610243,
 138.22279188368054,
 176.089111328125,
 155.05335489908853,
 145.78936089409723,
 41.650783962673614,
 152.47548082139758,
 136.87349785698785,
 130.15458509657117,
 115.51886664496527,
 111.95757378472223,
 106.1067606608073,
 135.65361870659723,
 152.4756096733941,
 142.81195068359375,
 119.00228881835938,
 139.1741197374132,
 145.24830457899304,
 106.11417304144965,
 153.58861626519098,
 120.68910725911458,
 155.5628187391493,
 126.3281012641059,
```

Где встречаются очень близкие числа.Например, 0 и 7 элементы массива
Можно ли как-то найти все такие близкие числа? Нужно количество таких пар

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сортируете список чисел, перебираете в цикле первое число со вторым, второе с третьим и т.д. Если разница между двумя числами незначительная, пара близких чисел найдена:

```
def is_small_equal(a: float, b: float) -> bool:
    return abs(a - b) <= 0.01


items = [117.81008911132812, 116.40049913194444, 132.6966349283854, 139.83181762695312, 129.08833482530383, 99.76490953233507, 132.69677734375, 117.81746080186632, 132.66025119357639, 100.42313300238715, 105.30181545681424, 155.56293063693576, 120.6885986328125, 107.1498514811198, 100.41515435112848, 105.30535888671875, 155.5640394422743, 132.65536159939236, 137.21171061197916, 150.28360324435764, 116.40386962890625, 172.6755608452691, 136.65747748480902, 139.99466281467014, 137.20905558268228, 144.14166937934027, 137.97456868489584, 144.14078097873264, 172.5401136610243, 138.22279188368054, 176.089111328125, 155.05335489908853, 145.78936089409723, 41.650783962673614, 152.47548082139758, 136.87349785698785, 130.15458509657117, 115.51886664496527, 111.95757378472223, 106.1067606608073, 135.65361870659723, 152.4756096733941, 142.81195068359375, 119.00228881835938, 139.1741197374132, 145.24830457899304, 106.11417304144965, 153.58861626519098, 120.68910725911458, 155.5628187391493, 126.3281012641059]
items.sort()

for i in range(len(items) - 1):
    a, b = items[i], items[i + 1]
    if is_small_equal(a, b):
        print(a, b)
```

Результат:

```
100.41515435112848 100.42313300238715
105.30181545681424 105.30535888671875
106.1067606608073 106.11417304144965
116.40049913194444 116.40386962890625
117.81008911132812 117.81746080186632
120.6885986328125 120.68910725911458
132.65536159939236 132.66025119357639
132.6966349283854 132.69677734375
137.20905558268228 137.21171061197916
144.14078097873264 144.14166937934027
152.47548082139758 152.4756096733941
155.5628187391493 155.56293063693576
155.56293063693576 155.5640394422743
```

Comment: думал пройти list, но искал более оптимизированное решение)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: а первое число с 10-м, например, не нужно разве сравнивать? Неверное решение у вас, нужно два вложенных цикла, чтобы все возможные пары чисел сравнить

Comment: @suit в этом решении список сначала сортируется. то есть в любом случае два числа. находящиеся рядом будут иметь наименьшую разность по сравнению с остальными. а решение сводится к тому, чтобы найти числа, разность которых удовлетворяет заданному порогу

Comment: @strawdog в задаче не указано, что число может иметь только одно близкое число. В целом, там, конечно, вообще не сказано, что такое "близкие числа". Но если порог "близости" можно задавать руками, то у первого числа близкие могут быть и 2-е, и 3-е и т.д.

Comment: @suit да нет, в задаче как раз все сказано - необходимо найти пары. другое дело, что есть вероятность появления пар с одинаковыми разностями, но это легко лечится оборачиванием результата во множество (set)

Comment: @strawdog 1-е число и 3-е число это не пара?) или если в одну пару число попало, то в другую не может? Если так, то по этому алгоритму 2-число может попасть в пару с первым и с третьим.

Comment: @suit и попадет в пару и с тем, и с другим, если разность соответствует порогу

Comment: @strawdog как раз этого условия нет в задаче

Comment: @suit чего нет в условии? порога? порог -  единственный косяк этого решения. а вот пермутация пар с одинаковым порогом - вполне себе ок.

Answer (score 3):

```
def pairs(lst):
    lst.sort()
    for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
        if abs(lst[i]-lst[i+1])<0.01:
            yield [lst[i], lst[i+1]]

print(list(pairs(lst)))
```

на выходе:

```
[[100.41515435112848, 100.42313300238715],
[105.30181545681424, 105.30535888671875],
[106.1067606608073, 106.11417304144965],
[116.40049913194444, 116.40386962890625],
[117.81008911132812, 117.81746080186632],
[120.6885986328125, 120.68910725911458],
[132.65536159939236, 132.66025119357639],
[132.6966349283854, 132.69677734375],
[137.20905558268228, 137.21171061197916],
[144.14078097873264, 144.14166937934027],
[152.47548082139758, 152.4756096733941],
[155.5628187391493, 155.56293063693576],
[155.56293063693576, 155.5640394422743]]
```

Для наглядности:

```
lst1=[11.0003, 11.0001, 11.0002, 11.0004]

def pairs(lst):
    lst.sort()
    for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
        if abs(lst[i]-lst[i+1])<0.01:
            yield [lst[i], lst[i+1]]

print(list(pairs(lst1)))

[[11.0001, 11.0002], [11.0002, 11.0003], [11.0003, 11.0004]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
items = [117.81008911132812, 116.40049913194444, 132.6966349283854, 139.83181762695312, 129.08833482530383, 99.76490953233507, 132.69677734375, 117.81746080186632, 132.66025119357639, 100.42313300238715, 105.30181545681424, 155.56293063693576, 120.6885986328125, 107.1498514811198, 100.41515435112848, 105.30535888671875, 155.5640394422743, 132.65536159939236, 137.21171061197916, 150.28360324435764, 116.40386962890625, 172.6755608452691, 136.65747748480902, 139.99466281467014, 137.20905558268228, 144.14166937934027, 137.97456868489584, 144.14078097873264, 172.5401136610243, 138.22279188368054, 176.089111328125, 155.05335489908853, 145.78936089409723, 41.650783962673614, 152.47548082139758, 136.87349785698785, 130.15458509657117, 115.51886664496527, 111.95757378472223, 106.1067606608073, 135.65361870659723, 152.4756096733941, 142.81195068359375, 119.00228881835938, 139.1741197374132, 145.24830457899304, 106.11417304144965, 153.58861626519098, 120.68910725911458, 155.5628187391493, 126.3281012641059]

def k_closest(sample, pivot, k):
    return sorted(sample, key=lambda i: abs(i - pivot))[:k]

rez = [ k_closest(items, i, 2)    for i in items]

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(rez)
[[117.81008911132812, 117.81746080186632],
 [116.40049913194444, 116.40386962890625],
 [132.6966349283854, 132.69677734375],
 [139.83181762695312, 139.99466281467014],
 [129.08833482530383, 130.15458509657117],
 [99.76490953233507, 100.41515435112848],
 [132.69677734375, 132.6966349283854],
 [117.81746080186632, 117.81008911132812],
 ...
 [106.11417304144965, 106.1067606608073],
 [153.58861626519098, 152.4756096733941],
 [120.68910725911458, 120.6885986328125],
 [155.5628187391493, 155.56293063693576],
 [126.3281012641059, 129.08833482530383]]
```